# Feature Request: Citing Tweets

Tags: feature-request, citations, hyperlinks

I'd like to paste in a Twitter URL and get a nicely formatted quote with a link back to the original, the Twitter user, date, etc. Lately—primarily due to the convenience of reaching D&D 5e designers—we've been [citing tweets](//rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77738/war-caster-feat-and-green-flame-blade-is-it-legit) by hand, and it could look a lot better if it were automatic in some way.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would a citation from Twitter appear different from a by-hand citation? And do other sites have features that automatically format things like tweets? (I'd really just like to see an example of what you're asking for.)

Comment: Also, this might not be an RPG-specific request - it's worth considering asking about it on MSE, since it's likely to get more eyes on it there.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Tweets are oneboxed in chat, I'm guessing okeefe is asking for something similar.

Comment: @HeyICanChan The url for a [single tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/651801858130898944) is pretty close, in particular the entirety of the tweet text (and inclusion of another tweet in this case), name, twitter handle, date & time. Number of likes and retweets could be useful. No need for the follow or reply buttons or the list of replies. We could also add CSS so it looks more like our existing quote.